# cv::Mat_ to std::vector conversion

Tags: c++, stl, visual-studio-2005, vector, opencv

I use OpenCV 2.0, there is a method in the `cv::Mat_<_Tp>` class:

```
// conversion to vector.
operator vector<_Tp>() const;
```

When instantiated, the implementation does not compile on MSVS 2005:

```
template<typename _Tp> inline Mat_<_Tp>::operator vector<_Tp>() const
{
    CV_Assert( rows == 1 || cols == 1 );
    return isContinuous() ? vector<_Tp>((size_t)(rows + cols - 1), (_Tp*)data) :
        (vector<_Tp>)((Mat_<_Tp>)this->t());
}
```

Is it a new fancy constructor of `std::vector` that takes `size_t` and `_Tp*` from TR1 or something?

I thought they could just initialize the vector by an iterator instead:

```
vector<_Tp>((_Tp*)data, (_Tp*)data + rows + cols - 1)
```

Is it a bug, or don't I know something?

UPD. Compiler error text:

```
...\lib\opencv\include\opencv\cxmat.hpp(691) : error C2665: 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector' : none of the 6 overloads could convert all the argument types
        with
        [
            _Ty=double
        ]
        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\vector(473): could be 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector(__w64 unsigned int,const _Ty &)'
        with
        [
            _Ty=double
        ]
        while trying to match the argument list '(size_t, double *)'
        ...\lib\opencv\include\opencv\cxmat.hpp(689) : while compiling class template member function 'cv::Mat_<_Tp>::operator std::vector<_Ty>(void) const'
        with
        [
            _Tp=double,
            _Ty=double
        ]
        z:\dev\mine\temp\temp\entry.cpp(37) : see reference to class template instantiation 'cv::Mat_<_Tp>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Tp=double
        ]
```

Comment: Can you post the compiler error you are getting?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y I've added it, but I doubt it can help. The message just says there is no suitable overload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are new constructors from rvalues in C++0x, but nothing like the one used here.

If isContinuous() means that all vales are the same, you could possibly use `vector<_Tp>((size_t)(rows + cols - 1), *(_Tp*)data)` to make copies of the first value.

Your iterator version seems correct otherwise.

Comment: Bo, the function may copy the whole data since it is a conversion routine. I guess isContinuous() means the matrix is single-row and thus stored in memory continuously, and we should not transpose it.

Comment: isCOntinuous() means that the data is just rows*cols, if the row isn't a multiple of 32bits openCV pads the data so that each new row begins on a 4byte boundary

Comment: Ok, then they **are** using a constructor that isn't available. Looks like a bug to me!