# Converting a row of cv::Mat to std::vector

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, copy

I have a fairly simple question: how to take one row of `cv::Mat` and get all the data in `std::vector`? The `cv::Mat` contains `doubles` (it can be any simple datatype for the purpose of the question).

Going through OpenCV documentation is just very confusing, unless I bookmark the page I can not find a documentation page twice by Googling, there's just to much of it and not easy to navigate.

I have found the `cv::Mat::at(..)` to access the Matrix element, but I remember from `C OpenCV` that there were at least 3 different ways to access elements, all of them used for different purposes... Can't remember what was used for which :/

So, while copying the Matrix element-by-element will surely work, I am looking for a way that is *more efficient* and, if possible, *a bit more elegant* than a for loop for each row.

Comment: I think it's a duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405070/cvmat-to-stdvector-conversion

Comment: @piokuc I saw that one, but that was platform specific  (Visual Studio), for OpenCV 2.0 (older version than today) *and* concerning a specific `cv::Mat` wrapper `cv::Mat_`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Data in OpenCV matrices is laid out in row-major order, so that each row is guaranteed to be contiguous.  That means that you can interpret the data in a row as a plain C array.  The following example comes directly from [the documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat):

```
// compute sum of positive matrix elements
// (assuming that M is double-precision matrix)
double sum=0;
for(int i = 0; i < M.rows; i++)
{
    const double* Mi = M.ptr<double>(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < M.cols; j++)
        sum += std::max(Mi[j], 0.);
}
```

Therefore the most efficient way is to pass the plain pointer to `std::vector`:

```
// Pointer to the i-th row
const double* p = mat.ptr<double>(i);

// Copy data to a vector.  Note that (p + mat.cols) points to the
// end of the row.
std::vector<double> vec(p, p + mat.cols);
```

This is certainly faster than using the iterators returned by `begin()` and `end()`, since those involve extra computation to support gaps between rows.

Answer (score 34):

It should be as simple as:

```
m.row(row_idx).copyTo(v);
```

Where `m` is `cv::Mat` having `CV_64F` depth and `v` is `std::vector<double>`

Comment: wow this is great. But, since I actually needed to create a new vector and fill it with data, I think just giving the pointers to the vector constructor will work better in this case.

Comment: this should be the answer. So simple!

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation at [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat), you can get a specific row through `cv::Mat::row`, which will return a new `cv::Mat`, over which you can iterator with `cv::Mat::begin` and `cv::Mat::end`. As such, the following should work:

```
cv::Mat m/*= initialize */;
// ... do whatever...
cv::Mat first_row(m.row(0));
std::vector<double> v(first_row.begin<double>(), first_row.end<double>());
```

Note that I don't know any OpenCV, but googling "OpenCV mat" led directly to the basic types documentation and according to that, this should work fine.

> The matrix iterators are random-access iterators, so they can be passed to any STL algorithm, including std::sort() .

This is also from the documentiation, so you could actually do this without a copy:

```
cv::Mat m/*= initialize */;
// ... do whatever...
// first row          begin              end
std::vector<double> v(m.begin<double>(), m.begin<double>() + m.size().width);
```

To access more than the first row, I'd recommend the first snippet, since it will be a lot cleaner that way and there doesn't seem to be any heavy copying since the data types seem to be reference-counted.

Comment: Did you mean `m.size().width` in your second example?  Note that OpenCV matrices are stored row-major and you are adding the number of *rows* when you should probably be adding the number of *columns*.

Comment: @Ferdinand: Woops, yes, that was indeed what I intended. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Instead of `m.size().width`, you can directly use `m.cols`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `cv::Rect`

```
m(cv::Rect(0, 0, 1, m.cols))
```

will give you first row.

```
matrix(cv::Rect(x0, y0, len_x, len_y);
```

means that you will get `sub_matrix` from `matrix` whose upper left corner is `(x0,y0)` and size is `(len_x, len_y)`. `(row,col)`

Comment: it should be `m(cv::Rect(0, 0, m.cols, 1))`, not `1, m.cols`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works,

an example :

```
Mat Input(480, 720, CV_64F, Scalar(100));
```

cropping the 1st row of the matrix:

```
Rect roi(Point(0, 0), Size(720, 1));
```

then:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > vector_of_rows;

vector_of_rows.push_back(Input(roi));
```