# How to convert a cv::Mat Image to an std::vector if the Image is not continuous?

Tags: opencv

I tried looking for solutions and came across this link
[Converting a row of cv::Mat to std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790124/converting-a-row-of-cvmat-to-stdvector) .However, the answer here will only work if the image is continuous i.e length of a row = step size . Am I right or am I missing something? If I'm right, what is the most efficient way of copying a non-continuous image to a std::vector?

I am looking for something more efficient than,

```
for(int ii=0;ii<no. of image rows;ii++)
{
    ptr = pointer to ii'th row
    copy from ptr to (ptr+row length) into std::vector
}
```

Thanks,

Vishy

Comment: I think you're missing something (or perhaps I am), I can't see why there is a problem.

Comment: Consider a 800 * 300 (8-bit single channel) image. This image consists of 800*300 = 240000 pixels . The link I've posted suggests that starting from the base address of the image I can copy the next 240000 address locations to a vector and I'll have converted the cv::Mat to a std:vector. However, if the image is padded, then a row  will have length 800+p (800 actual values and 'p' padding values. Which means if now I copy the next 240000 addresses blindly to the vector, then I'll end up with a lot of garbage values. Does that make sense?

Comment: The one you had is good enough. I don't think there is more efficient way.

Comment: why would you want to do this?  You can get iterators to rows in a cv::Mat without copying the data...

Comment: @Hammer : Well, I wanted to put the image data into a vector so that I could manipulate it using standard vector methods. In any case, the iterators suggestion was nice.I can now convert the cv::Mat into a std::vector using this < dstVec.assign(srcVec.begin(),srcVec.end()); >

Comment: @Vishy Glad it helped.  Is that actually faster though?  I would have actually expected it to be slower

Answer (score 0):

For a single channel 8-bit image,

```
std::vector<uchar> dstVec;
dstVec.assign(srcVec.begin(),srcVec.end());
```