# Converting a cv::Mat into a vector<int>

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I want to put the data from a `cv:Mat` into a normal C++ `vector`.
I know that I can reshape the `cv::Mat` into a vector with `mat.reshape ( 0, 1 )`

How can put the data into a `vector`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a row of cv::Mat to std::vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790124/converting-a-row-of-cvmat-to-stdvector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cv::Mat` has a conversion operator to `std::vector`, provided the vector has the proper data type.

```
cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_8UC1);
std::vector<uchar> v = m.reshape(0, 1);
```