# Getting value-type of cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm creating a module that should accept an OpenCV matrix. I'm new to OpenCV and effectively not using the library, so maybe my question is naive.

I would like to have a function that accepts OpenCV types as widely as possible (`cv::Mat`, `cv::Mat_<T>`, `cv::Matx<T,M,N>`), however I need to know the underlying value-type at compile-time.

My question is: Is the value-type known at compile-time for `cv::Mat`? It seems that [one can cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790384/2646505), and that [one can extract](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43215654/2646505) it at run-time. But can it be found at compile-time? My guess is no, because the underlying value-type is non-standard. But if it is known, how do I get it?

This does not seem to work:

```cpp
template <class T>
inline void foo(const T& bar)
{
    using value_type = typename std::decay_t<T>::value_type;
}
```

Comment: You can't find the type of `cv::Mat` at compile time. For `cv::Mat_<T>` you can, it's specified by the template parameter, and you can't store any other type of data in it. Not sure what you mean by `cv::Mat_<T,M,N>`... maybe you mixed that up with the `Matx` template?

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks! Yeah, I guess I meant `Matx`, I'll edit. But in general the question is if I template brutally (like in now in the question), how do I get the value-type?